# set item at multiple indexes in a list

Tags: python, map-function

I am trying to find a way to use a list of indexes to set values at multiple places in a list (as is possible with numpy arrays).

I found that I can map `__getitem__` and a list of indexes to return the values at those indexes:

```
# something like
a_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
idxs = [0, 1]
get_map = map(a_list.__getitem__, idxs) 

print(list(get_map)) # yields ['a', 'b']
```

However, when applying this same line of thought to `__setitem__`, the setting fails. This probably has something to do with pass-by-reference vs pass-by-value, which I have never fully understood no matter how many times I've read about it.

**Is there a way to do this?**

```
b_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
idxs = [0, 1]
put_map = map(b_list.__setitem__, idx, ['YAY', 'YAY'])

print(b_list) # yields ['YAY', 'YAY', 'c']
```

For my use case, I only want to set one value at multiple locations. Not multiple values at multiple locations.

**EDIT**: I know how to use list comprehension. I am trying to mimic `numpy`'s capability to accept a list of indexes for both getting and setting items in an array, except for lists.

Comment: @mkrieger1 The last example doesn't work. It yields nothing, and `b_list` remains unchanged. I was just trying to give an example of what I want to achieve.

Comment: You never consume the map, thus the instructions are not executed. Try `list(put_map)` which yields only `[None, None]`, but afterwards `b_list` is as expected.

Comment: @mkrieger1, nothing I suppose. I just figured using map might be somehow faster.

Comment: why `dictionary` is used as a tag?

Comment: @tobias_k Ah! Okay, I see what you mean! Okay, so the only nuisance is that if I have a single value I want at multiple locations, I have to make a list of `['Yay', 'Yay', ..., 'Yay']`. But I guess that's not so bad.

Comment: @balderman because if you type `dictionary` you will see that it says "also: map" and I am using a map.

Comment: Look at the `map` docs,  "Make an iterator that computes the function using arguments from each of the iterables.".  `list(map(...))` is functionally similar to a list comprehension, with minor speed differences.  This use of the word "map" is not the same as the "dictionary==map" usage.

Comment: The standard `operator` module has an `itemgetter` function, https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html.  Look at its equivalent. Or the actual code in the `operator.py` file.  It's written as a class, but the basic operation is `tuple(obj[i] for i in items)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the `get` and `set` case is that in the `get` case you are interested in the result of `map` itself, but in the `set` case you want a side effect. Thus, you never consume the `map` generator and the instructions are never actually executed. Once you do, `b_list` gets changed as expected.

```
>>> put_map = map(b_list.__setitem__, idxs, ['YAY', 'YAY']) 
>>> b_list                                                                  
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> list(put_map)                                                           
[None, None]
>>> b_list                                                                 
['YAY', 'YAY', 'c']
```

Having said that, the proper way for `get` would be a list comprehension and for `set` a simple `for` loop. That also has the advantage that you do not have to repeat the value to put in place n times.

```
>>> for i in idxs: b_list[i] = "YAY"                                       
>>> [b_list[i] for i in idxs]                                              
['YAY', 'YAY']
```

Comment: Thanks. Is `map` not going to be faster than list comprehension? I just wonder because numpy allows for this sort of operation, although I don't know how it is achieved.

Comment: I don't think `map` is faster than a list comprehension. But it is a common pitfall in performance testing to test only the `map` creation (as you did) without actually evaluating/consuming the map and thus seeing it being massively faster than an equivalent list comprehension.

Comment: I mean with list comprehension you have to iterate through a maximum of N items. But with a map, you have only to iterate through the specific indexes you'd like to get/set. I guess this is a small difference in the grand scheme of things? Anyway, I'll accept your answer and ask a different one on how NumPy achieves this functionality.

Comment: No, note that I did not do `[b_list[i] for i in range(len(b_list)) if i in idxs]` but `[b_list[i] for i in idxs]`, thus I only iterate the indices that I want. Same for the `for` loop. Numpy may have some performance optimizations, but in the end it's O(k) for k indices out of a list of n elements.