# How does numpy achieve the functionality of passing a list as an index to both get and set items?

Tags: python, list, numpy

I just asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66697488/set-item-at-multiple-indexes-in-a-list/66697597#66697597) because I was trying to figure out a way to get and set multiple items at once using a list of indexes, much like how things work with numpy arrays. I got a good answer to the question as I posted it, and feel that it is right to accept it. Therefore I will ask a more specific question here:

How does NumPy achieve this functionality:

```
x = np.arange(3)
x[[0,2]] = 999
print(x) # yields [999, 1, 999]
```

and

```
print(x[[0, 1]]) # yields [999, 1]
```

Is it simply a for loop under the hood, or something more complicated?

Comment: `numpy` does this in compiled code.  So it's not easy to study the details.  It does iterate as needed.  `np.nditer` gives a flavor of how `numpy` iterates, but the `c` version is much faster.

Comment: I don't think details of how `numpy` works will help you with lists.  As a python programmer you don't have direct access to the compiled code of either class.

Comment: In all cases the indexing is translated to `obj.__getitem__(indices)` or `obj.__setitme__(indices, values)`, where `indices` may be a value (e.g. number, list) or a `tuple`.  A list can only handle a few kinds `indices`, which you can see from an error message.  A `ndarray` handles a lot more, but the details are all under the covers.

Comment: That makes sense. I figured it might not be so easy, but I was curious. Thanks.